# A modern reference to the Zsigmondy Theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

I need to cite the classical [Zsigmondy Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem), which was proved in 1892.

Is there any modern reference to this theorem?

I mean some standard textbook in Number Theory containing this theorem together with the proof.

Comment: If you just need to cite the theorem, what's wrong with citing the original source?

Comment: In *Linear Forms in Logarithms and Applications* by Yann Bugeaud, European Mathematical Society, 2018, there are mentions and references on pages 95 and 106

Comment: I plan to include both the original course and the modern one (for those that do not read German, for example).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

M. Teleuca, Zsigmondy's theorem and its applications in contest problems, International Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology Volume 44, 2013 - Issue 3, Pages 443-451, https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0020739X.2012.714493?mobileUi=0&journalCode=tmes20

The abstract begins, "In this article, we present a detailed proof of Zsigmondy's theorem."

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660585/elementary-proof-of-zsigmondys-theorem and Moshe Roitman, On Zsigmondy primes, Proceedings of the
American Mathematical Society, Volume 125, Number 7, July 1997, Pages 1913–1919, https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-07/S0002-9939-97-03981-6/S0002-9939-97-03981-6.pdf

Comment: There are also notes of Jameson on cyclotomic polynomials.  A MathOverflow search should reveal the link.  It has  a proof following Roitman.  Gerhard "My Goto For Cyclotomic Polynomials" Paseman, 2020.06.22.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, it is very difficult to find Zsigmondy's theorem with a proof in a book. However, it is proved in Appendix B to Chapter 30 in

**Berkovich, Ya. G.; Zhmudʹ, E. M.** *Characters of finite groups.* Part 2. Translated from the Russian manuscript by P. Shumyatsky [P. V. Shumyatskiĭ], V. Zobina and Berkovich. Translations of Mathematical Monographs, 181. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1999.